# Private extend in Java

Tags: java, c++, oop

In C++ we can extend (derive) a base class **privately** to a child class:

```
class Base
{
// ....
};

class Child : private Base
{
// ....
};
```

**What is Java's corresponding syntax ?**
If Java hasn't it, what do Java programmers?

Comment: We don't touch the private parts. ;-)

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma: I'd be quite worried if your children had access to the private members of your class ;)

Comment: In general we try not to violate the basics of OOP and encapsulation.. If you want parts of your class to be extendable, make them protected. Private fields are an implementation detail.

Comment: you should read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html

Comment: @Voo:Well, in C++ friends can access our private parts :)

Comment: My `private` parts are `private`! And that's `final`! Only `class`-mates can see them. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's syntax for inheritance:

```
class Base {}
class Child extends Base
{
  // ...
}
```

There is no private inheritance in Java. Java only has public inheritance. That is, you both inherit implementation and interface.

With private inheritance, you would only inherit implementation. It's basically a more static form of composition, as far as I remember.

In most cases, you can use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) to do the same thing.

```
public class Child{
   private Base base;

   public Child(...){
       base = new Base(...);
   }
}
```

Comment: More than composition it should be considered as when the inheritance is an implementation detail. Consider a class with a given interface to its users, that in a particular implementation needs to extend a different interface for some reason (that is not part of its contract). In C++ you can implement that interface privately, without your users being able to use that fact (I.e. your regular users cannot call methods other than the ones in your contract (public interface). Inheritance should *never* be used for composition.

Comment: I guess in java you would use an internal (or anonymous) class to implement the *private* interface, as the internal type will implicitly be able to acces your type.

Answer (score 3):

To a certain extent, you could use a private inner class to achieve a similar effect:

```
public class Base {

    private int privateMember = 10;

    private class Child extends Base {
        public Child() {
            System.out.println("I can see your privates: " + privateMember);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Base t = new Base();
        Child c = t.new Child();
    }

}
```

When running the above code, the following message gets printed on the console:

```
I can see your privates: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have any equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ private inheritance means actually: *is implemented in terms of*

I.e. it is an implementation technique used when you have 2 classes not having a *is-a* relationship but needs access to protected members or must redefine its virtual functions.

So by this definition you can do this in Java either by simply extending the class or using composition.

The syntax of *private* is just not available but you can get the same result